# Images not appearing in hostgator (cPanel) but appearing in localhost

Tags: html, css, path, localhost, cpanel

For some reason when I reference CSS files or image files in the hostgator index file (under public_html) they just don't work, but it works when I test it locally. Here is an example of me trying to use an image uploaded to the public_html folder via cPanel:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title>mydomain.com</title>
</head>

<h1>Here is an image</h1>
<img src="public_html/me.JPG" alt="pic of me">
<p style="background-color:#ECEBE9;">Here is more text

</p> 
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried:

- Changing the permissions (everything in public_html is 755 and
  public_html is 750 [as per hostgator's instructions](https://www.hostgator.com/help/article/public-html-folder))
- Using the full path: "/home/username/public_html/" (using my username and also trying "home3" instead of "home")
- Putting the JPG in a subfolder called images and using that path name

I'm assuming it's something obvious regarding the path, but I really don't understand why the index.html file can't access CSS or image files from the same folder on hostgator so please let me know anything else to try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if me.JPG is on the same folder that html doc, use src="me.JPG"

Use relative paths instead of absolute paths.

Comment: For some reason this works! Any idea why the absolute path is not working?

Answer (score 1):

```
<img src="public_html/me.JPG" alt="pic of me">
```

1. Can you take public_html and use the only me.JPG?
2. Please check the image extension .JPG or .jpg?

Comment: It is in fact .JPG and I tried swapping out my line of code for yours and I get the same result.

Comment: Can you check your code .jpg is uppercase?